# Azure AD dynamic group query error when using "and" to combine two working queries

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune, autopilot

Does anyone know how I can get this dynamic query working?

(device.deviceTrustType -ne "ServerAD") and (device.devicePhysicalIds -any "(_ -match "^[OrderID]:.*_AzureAD_UserDriven$")

***This works: (device.deviceTrustType -ne "ServerAD")

***This works: device.devicePhysicalIds -any "(_ -match "^[OrderID]:.*_AzureAD_UserDriven$")

But I can not bind them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the below

(device.devicePhysicalIds -any (_ -match "^[OrderID]:._AzureAD_UserDriven$")) and (device.deviceTrustType -ne "ServerAD")

I hope this version works for you. Let me know if you have any other concerns.